# mysql: date + 1 not working at crossover between months

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that selects all rows from my table `customers` where `s_date` is equal to `t_date` or one day after. Unfortunately, this seems to screw up when `t_date` is the last day of the month. It doesn't seem to understand that `t_date` + 1 = '2013-06-01'.

Anyway of making my query understand this?

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE t_date = '2013-05-31'
AND s_timestamp IS NOT NULL
AND s_date <= t_date + 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date_add( t_date, interval 1 day )`

***Refer to***: [**MySQL Date Functions: DATE_ADD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: @Ravinder, if you have to beg for votes, you don't deserve them.